# Will Apple reject a wait_fences warning?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Will app reject apps that receive

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

I've tried everything to get rid of the warning, but nothing so far... it doesn't effect my app at all, it just prints out.... so I submitted it to the Apple App store, but will they reject an app that gets this kind of warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warnings, generally, are not a huge deal and it will probably be fine.

Especially this warning, according to this post here: [wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 (Again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994998/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003-again)

> according to an apple engineer it is an issue caused internally and 3rd party developers should not worry about it.

Comment: «Warnings, generally, are not a huge deal»: I strongly disagree. In that specific case, it «should» be ok to ignore. But warnings are here for a reason. It may be portability issues, 64/32 bits issues, deprecation, possible race conditions, etc, etc... (to name only the most dangerous ones). If you think a warning is something you can simply ignore, as long as it's not an «error», and as long as it does not prevent the build phase, you'll be in trouble, sooner or later. If you got a warning, fix it, even if everything «works». You might not remember it when your app will start crashing.

Comment: Well, of course.  I simply meant that Apple doesn't care.  It's good practice to eliminate every warning or errors in the log output as you can.  You can code badly, generate tons of runtime and compiler warnings, and as long as all your feature work on all supported devices, then Apple will not reject you. Whether they _should_ reject you for that is not part of this discussion :)