# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 error occur while click on button (send, cancel) of MFmessgecompose model iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I want to popup `MFMessageCompose` model on (topviewcontroller) from another `NSObject` class method which is executed in background.

I popup `MFMessageCompose` model using this code :

```
MFMessageComposeViewController * controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = @"Check out FundooSpace for mobile.Download it now from app.fundoospace.net/FundooSpace/d";
    controller.recipients = (NSArray *)passa;
    passa = nil;
    AppDelegate * appDelegateObject1 = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [appDelegateObject1.navigationCntr.topViewController presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
}
```

it works fine. but when i click on send or cancel button then app get crash and gives error is

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

please suggest me.

Comment: I want to pop up messagecompose model on topviewcontroller(it will be any)

Answer (score 0):

I exactly checked the code what you included in your question and for me it is working nicely running on device.

1) make sure to have the delegate in your .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

2) You have to implement the delegate method also in your .m:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
    NSLog(@"didFinishWithResult");

    // you have to deal with the result var

    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"MyApp" 
                                message:@"Unknown Error"
                               delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@”OK” 
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

3) if you are on >iOS6.0 the "old" *presentModalViewController:animated* is deprecated, so change to *presentViewController:animated:completion:* as Xcode also indicates this.

Comment: As many SO article about wait_fences error, my working test also presents a wait_fence error.. If your app perfectly runs on device you can ignore this message (eg. according to this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9046838/2129209)

Comment: Also others said that some delaying could help when presenting modal view, since iOS framework might have some resource-run issue when quickly presenting modal view.  So I tried for your code including this:  [self performSelector:@selector(showmsg) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];    and making the messagecomposer show method into showmsg.  Still wait_fences error is coming, but test-app works prefectly, sends sms nicely.